# Is it possible to add Custom 403 Error page in Azure Web Apps

Tags: azure, paas, error-handling

We have built our Sitecore 9.1 solution in Azure Web Apps. We have added custom `403` and `400` error pages by making use of the Error Manager module from Sitecore https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Sitecore_Error_Manager.aspx.

It is working locally with `IIS`. But when it is deployed to Azure Web Apps, it is showing `403` page from Azure with the error message `Error 403 - This web app is stopped.` instead of custom pages which we added in Sitecore application for both 400 and 403 Http status codes.

How to add custom error pages for `403` and `400`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50166342/6144330

Answer (score 2):

For the case of `Error 403 - This web app is stopped.` - this is not easily possible since it is actually the built-in Azure load balancer that is serving the error, not the WebApp or Sitecore.

You can track the status of this feature on [Azure Feedback portal and vote for it](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/cae2d76b-c825-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0f1c).

There is a possible workaround: you can route all traffic to your WebApp via your own load balancer or [Application Gateway](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/custom-error) and have a custom static error page for these HTTP status codes.

For the case of 400 (Bad Request) this should be working and is perhaps an issue with the Sitecore error manager module. Please update your question or post a new question with exact request and response details.

Comment: The azure feedback url is now https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/cae2d76b-c825-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0f1c

Comment: Thanks , updated